# DRF: Disable GET request on the base url route path

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

This is my urlpatterns in base urls.py,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include((router.urls, 'api'), namespace='api')),
]
```

when I browse to `localhost:8000/api/`, it exposes all my routes,

```
{
    "accounts": "http://localhost:8000/api/accounts/",
    "cases":"http://localhost:8000/api/cases/",
    "issues": "http://localhost:8000/api/issues/"
}
```

Is there any way I can disable this exposing on django application level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `SimpleRouter` instead of `DefaultRouter`. The latter adds the view to the routing provided by the former.